# Missing an assembly reference Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2010

I installed Crystal Reports for VS 2010 from http://www.sdn.sap.com
When I create new Crystal Report in the CrystalReport.cs class there are few errors:

> The type or namespace name 'Engine' does not exist in the namespace
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

I manually browsed the `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll` and added it to the References but still gives me the error

The same error gives me for CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
The same error gives me for CrystalDecisions.Shared

Also the `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` doesn't exist when I go to Add Reference .NET tab ..

Comment: This may seem like a silly thing, but I had this problem because I had already installed CR for VS2010 in Windows 8 before I actually installed VS2010. So, I went to Programs & Features, removed the SAP program listed and re-installed the Support Pack 4 Runtime Package. It works fine, now.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who has still this problem:
Somehow i figured out that there are problems with .NET 4, with .NET 4.5 & VS2012 they just work fine.

I haven't tried Ally's solution but that maybe is the right answer to my problems, but whatever i switched to vs2012 & 4.5 so they work just fine.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You Must Change Version Of .Net In Project Properties. In Tab Application, Change Target framework To .Net Framework 4. I exactly had problem. In fact, initial .Net Framework When I created Project was .Net Framework 4 Client Profile. As I told, I changed to .Net framework 4.

Problem solved perfectly.